# Dynamically create array in bash with variables as array name

Tags: bash, array

This has been asked several times, but none of the methods work. I would like to dynamically create arrays with array names taken from the variables. So lets start with just one array for now:

```
#!/bin/bash
i="aaa"
eval ${i}=("1")
```

results in

```
./1.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./1.sh: line 3: `eval ${i}=("1")'
```

same result with:

```
$(eval ${i})=('1')
$(eval echo ${i})=('1')
$(eval "echo ${i}")=('1')
```

I do not want to eval everything, justthe array name. If it is possible I would like to avoid using eval at all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`eval` expects a string as the argument. You can't use `(` unquoted, it has a special meaning in shell.

```
i=aaa
eval "$i=(1 2)"  # Use a string, $i will expand in double quotes.
echo ${aaa[1]}
```

You can also use `declare` or `typeset` instead of `eval`:

```
declare -a $i='(1 2)'
```

You still have to quote the parentheses and spaces.

To avoid `eval` completely, you can assign one by one:

```
#! /bin/bash
name=aaa
values=(1 2)
for ((i=0; i<${#values[@]}; ++i)) ; do
    read "$name[$i]" <<< "${values[i]}"
done
echo ${aaa[1]}
```

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: @meso_2600: I updated the answer.

Comment: The `read` variant is fantastic! At last a alternative to `eval`! The problem with `declare`/`typeset` is that in functions the declared variable is local to the function.

Comment: @t0r0X Use `declare -g` or `declare -x` within function to make it global/export.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to load the array without using `eval`. It doesn't use the `( data )` construct - instead it uses an input string with your choice of delimiter - the example uses `|`

```
i=aaa
IFS='|' read -a "$i" <<<"1|2   with spaces"
printf '%s\n' "${aaa[@]}"
```

Output:

```
1
2   with spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `declare` with dynamic names and values, and variable indirection to reference variables based upon their name.  `printf '%q'` can help you "shell-escape" values so that they can be used during dynamic assignments.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a products=( phone computer )
printf 'Product: %s\n' "${products[@]}"
# Product: phone
# Product: computer
unset products

declare varName='products'
declare -a "${varName}"='( cell\ phone laptop\ computer )'
declare arrayRef="${varName}[@]"
printf 'Product: %s\n' "${!arrayRef}"
# Product: cell phone
# Product: laptop computer
unset "${varName}"

declare -a toCopy=( 'LED TV' '"Smart" car' )
declare -a "${varName}"="( $( printf '%q ' "${toCopy[@]}" ) )"
printf 'Product: %s\n' "${!arrayRef}"
# Product: LED TV
# Product: "Smart" car
unset "${varName}"
```